# Issues trying to add VNET Service Endpoints in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I currently have an ARM Template that deploys a Virtual Network with a Subnet along with an Azure SQL Database instance.

The core resources related to the Subnet and SQL Firewall Rules are:

```
        {
            "name": "MyVirtualNetwork",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Client-Subnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "name": "NDC-VirtualNetwork/Client-Subnet",
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'NDC-VirtualNetwork')]"
            ]
        }
```

and

```
               {
                    "type": "firewallRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                    "properties": {
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "firewallRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "name": "ClientIP",
                    "properties": {
                        "startIpAddress": "[parameters('clientIP')]",
                        "endIpAddress": "[parameters('clientIP')]"
                    }
                }
```

I now want to update the Template to permit VNET Service Endpoints from this Subnet to access SQL and to remove the "AllowAllWindowsAzureIPs" and "ClientIP" firewall rules.

To achieve this, I remove both *firewallRules* resources from the SQL resource and add the following:

```
                {
                    "name": "[concat(variables('uniqueSQLName'), '-Client-Subnet')]",
                    "type": "virtualNetworkRules",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                    "properties": {
                        "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'NDC-VirtualNetwork', 'Client-Subnet')]",
                        "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": true
                    },
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]"
                    ]
                }
```

and then update the Networking resources to :

```
        {
            "name": "MyVirtualNetwork",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Client-Subnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
                            },
                            "serviceEndpoints": [
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "australiaeast"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "name": "AllowVNETtoSQL",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'MyVirtualNetwork')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "serviceEndpointPolicyDefinitions": [
                    {
                        "name": "AllowVNETtoSQLPolicy",
                        "properties": {
                            "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                            "serviceResources": [
                                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "name": "MyVirtualNetwork/Client-Subnet",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks','MyVirtualNetwork')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies','AllowVNETtoSQL')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "serviceEndpointPolicies": [
                    {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies','AllowVNETtoSQL')]"
                    }
                ],
                "serviceEndpoints": [
                    {
                        "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                        "locations": [
                            "australiaeast"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

I get two errors from this change:

1. Azure SQL Server Virtual Network Rule encountered an user error: Cannot proceed with operation because subnets Client-Subnet of the virtual network
   /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/MyVirtualNetwork are not provisioned. They are in Updating state.
2. Service endpoint policy definition
   /subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies/AllowVNETtoSQL/serviceEndpointPolicyDefinitions/AllowVNETtoSQLPolicy references
   an invalid service name Microsoft.Sql. Supported service names are: Microsoft.Storage, Microsoft.Sql, Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory, Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB, Microsoft.Web,
   Microsoft.NetworkServiceEndpointTest, Microsoft.KeyVault, Microsoft.EventHub, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Microsoft.ContainerRegistry, Microsoft.CognitiveServices, Global. (Code:
   ServiceEndpointPolicyDefinitionHasServiceWithInvalidServiceName)

My questions are as follows:

1. Can anyone explain the second error where it states Microsoft.Sql is invalid but then lists it as the supported service names?
2. What am I missing with Dependencies to allow the Service Endpoints to complete deployment?  I already have the SQL Virtual Network Rule with the property `"ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": true`  My understanding of this is that the SQL resource would create the Service Endpoint firewall rule OK and skip any checking of the Subnet state and the Subnet would then happily transition into the enabled state and future connections would be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got this to work as follows:

For the virtualNetworkRules I added a dependency to the subnet

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('uniqueSQLName'), '/ClientSubnet')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('uniqueSQLName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'MyVirtualNetwork', 'Client-Subnet')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'MyVirtualNetwork', 'Client-Subnet')]",
                "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": true
            }
        }
```

I then updated the virtualNetwork to:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "MyVirtualNetwork",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Client-Subnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
                            },
                            "serviceEndpoints": [
                                {
                                    "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                                    "locations": [
                                        "[resourceGroup().location]"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "PrivateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Disabled",
                            "PrivateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Disabled"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

and included a subnet resource:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[concat('MyVirtualNetwork', '/Client-Subnet')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'MyVirtualNetwork')]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
                },
                "serviceEndpoints": [
                    {
                        "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                        "locations": [
                            "[resourceGroup().location]"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "PrivateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Disabled",
                "PrivateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Disabled"
            }
        }
```

Everything seems to be happily working with that config.

NOTE - I also change the API version on some of these resources - not sure if that had an impact as well

Answer (score 0):

for point 1: add a dependson to the failing service to depend on the resources, that error should go away.
2. not sure, my guess would be - invisible characters or something like that. try copy\pasting from the error text.

for your questions: you dont need anything to enable service endpoints. just create them and then you can use them. ignore should work exactly like you think it should

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1, according to my research, now Azure service endpoint policies just support Azure storage service. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoint-policies-overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoint-policies-portal#create-a-service-endpoint-policy)

Regarding question 2, we need to create the vent firewall rule until the vent and subnet create successfully. Please update your template as following

```
 {
            "name": "MyVirtualNetwork",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "Client-Subnet",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "serviceEndpoints": [
                    {
                        "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                        "locations": [
                            "southeastasia"
                        ]
                    },
                            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('vmNSG'))]"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2019-11-01",
            "name": "NDC-VirtualNetwork/Client-Subnet",
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "serviceEndpoints": [
                    {
                        "service": "Microsoft.Sql",
                        "locations": [
                            ""
                        ]
                    }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'NDC-VirtualNetwork')]"
            ]
        },

       {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/virtualNetworkRules",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('uniqueSQLName'), '/newVnetRule1')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('uniqueSQLName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'NDC-VirtualNetwork', 'Client-Subnet')]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'NDC-VirtualNetwork', 'Client-Subnet')]",
                "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": true
            }
        }
```

Besides, the setting `ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint` is used to  tell azure server whether to check if the subnet has enabled service point. But **please note that before this rule is enhanced, you are required to turn VNet service endpoints On**. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#adding-a-vnet-firewall-rule-to-your-server-without-turning-on-vnet-service-endpoints)